# NHibernate failing to commit transaction due to image type

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate

I have a problem with NHibernate version 4.1.0 when trying to insert large images as byte array, in an image field in SQL Server. My mapping looks like this:

```
<property name="BinaryContent" column="MyContent" not-null="false" />
```

The problem is that is unable to commit the transaction. I think it's due to some truncation, since small images appear to be working well.

I have a workaround to this problem, changing the mapping and specifying the type:

```
<property name="BinaryContent" column="MyContent" not-null="false" type="BinaryBlob" />
```

But the problem is that is a very large project with many mapping files I have to change. So I'm looking forward to do this globally and automatically in the project.

Any solution?

(Note: in NHibernate 2.1 this was working like a charm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I fear.
For SQL-Server, you need your mappings to use the `BinaryBlob` type when you need a length greater than 8000, or you have to explicitly set your maxixum length on your mapping.
`byte[]` defaults to `Binary` if mapping type is not specified, see the [doc](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/mapping.html#mapping-types-basictypes). As for why this was working with NH 2.1, I do not know.

The [NH-2764](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2764) issue confirms this. (Closed as "Not an issue".)

Comment: Some earlier versions of NHibernate corrupted data by silently truncating in some circumstances.